# Existing code has no line break

Tags: css, code-cleanup

I am trying to modify a CSS file using Sublime Text 2, however, all the code is presented in one linebreaks with no line break whatsoever.

What can I do to change that into readable code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **[Code Beautifier](http://www.codebeautifier.com/)**. You input the code and it formats it for you. There are many other sites like this one so check around and see which one you like best.

If you want to use a Sublime Text plugin, try **[CSS Format](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/CSS%20Format)** by mutian.

**EDIT:** As said by [Imran Bughio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2697954/imran-bughio), **[CSS Beautify](http://cssbeautify.com/)** is another site like Code Beautifier.

**EDIT 2:** As noted by [Beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2217167/beginner), **[CSSLisible](http://csslisible.com/en/)** is another option.

Answer (score 1):

Go to this site [**CSSLISIBLE**](http://csslisible.com/en/). paste your css code and click Clean this code button..

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't vote more than one best answer. But your is one of them!

Comment: @user3525734 : its ok mate... no problem.. jsve answer is best one and cssbeautify.com also good..